# WP - woocommerce listing product categories by order

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, categories

I'm using (wordpress) woocommerce for the first time.

I'm trying to display all the product categories with their respective sub categories in a tree shape, but i cant seems to order them the way i'm ordering them in the back-end using drag and drop.

The WP get_terms() only allows order by id, name, count, slug and none.

The code i'm using is:

```
<?php $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => 0)); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php _e(get_permalink($catTerm->slug)); ?>"><?php _e($catTerm->name); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still haven't found a way to solve this problem using code so i'm going to just use a custom menu and then add the product categories from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using default woo functionality with no additional plugins.
First:
get_woocommerce_term_meta( $sub_category->term_id, 'order', true )

Then get all your categories and sort the array using this order.

```
$sortedMenu = array(); // new array
// menu var should be get_categories or taxonomy function return
// I also added order key/val in my category/term array item (along with other terms name, id etc)
// Then I sorted them like bellow
foreach( $menu as $key => $item ) $sortedMenu[$key] = $item['order'];
array_multisort( $sortedMenu, SORT_ASC, $menu );
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this has been a while since this issue has been posted but I have come across the same problem today and fixed it this way

```
$categories = $this->get_product_categories();
$categories_ordered = [];
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $meta = get_term_meta($category->term_id);
    $category->position = intval($meta['order'][0]);
    $categories_ordered[] = $category;
}
uasort($categories_ordered, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->position > $b->position;
});
```